# Getting error constructor LatLng in class LatLng cannot be applied to given types while working on Google map project

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

'LatLng()' has private access in 'com.google.type.LatLng'

Here is my code

```
 Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            smf.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title("You are Here...");
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Error

```
error: constructor LatLng in class LatLng cannot be applied to given types;
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                                        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Seems as if there is no `LatLng` constructor that takes 2 doubles. Which exact class did you use (i.e. fully qualified class name with package)? Did you check you're actually using that class and not imported some other class of the same name? What version of the library are you using?

Comment: I think error is due to this ('LatLng()' has private access in 'com.google.type.LatLng')

Comment: There is no same class with same name

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

Comment: Well, it looks like [`com.google.type.LatLng`](https://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/type/LatLng.html) doesn't have a public constructor but requires you to use a builder (there should be a `newBuilder()` method). Additionally it seems the "play-services" libraries use a different class, i.e. [`maps.model.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng).

Answer (score 0):

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Location.getLatitude(),Location.getLongitude());

Replace with this Lines

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete, did you miss posting part of it?